# Cant log from local (keyboard) only using ssh plus "sudo su" give error:

Tags: 22.04, login, sudo, su

I was messing with limits.conf and 99-sysctl.conf, and I became unable to access my system locally (i.e. using a keyboard). I cannot log in as any user, not even as `root`. I can only access my system via SSH, however, only as a regular user - I cannot log in as `root` over SSH because sudo su fails with the following error:

`su: cannot open session: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session`

I can still use sudo -i or sudo root /bin/bash, I reverted all the files back to their default state (from a backup), however, I still cannot access my system locally, only via SSH - and `sudo su` still fails.
I also tried creating a new user, however I experienced the same issue.

I would like to figure out hpw this was done, and fix it, if possible.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

If any system information or details are required, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you insist on the deprecated `sudo su` pattern instead of the proper `sudo -i`? Which of the following work or don't work?: `sudo su -c 'echo hi'` `sudo runuser -c 'echo hi'` `sudo runuser`? After you "reverted all" you need to reboot for them to apply. "Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session" is a PAM error. Look at the modification times in `/etc/pam.d/` and restore the files from another computer if you modified them

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i wanted to know why and how this happened so i can learn more about, not just a "reinstall or restore of the files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the file: **/etc/pam.d/common-session** i did add the follow lines to ensure root user load the settings for the test i was doing:

```
# Add this to ensure pam_limits.so is loaded.
# changed to test if this is the issue with sudo su
# This does break "su" and dont allow local login (keyboard)
#session required        pam_limits.so
```

atfer comented everything work normal.